# Well posedness dirichlet BC in elasticity

Tags: solid-mechanics

I always thought that a Dirichlet BC need to be prescribed on at least one part of the domain in order for linear elasticity to be well-posed. Is this correct?

But I was recently told by a colleague that this is not true and that the problem can be well-posed by specifying 2 tractions.

Comment: What PDE (or PDEs) are solved here?

Comment: You might be interested in the following answer: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/29413/9667

Comment: your colleague is correct... think about a free floating heated body ... of course you can solve this thermal expansion elasticity problem without fixing the body anywhere. you need to remove the 6 dofs rotation and translation of the solution space, that's it.